# A formula for the holomorphic sectional curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-manifolds

I tried to compute the holomorphic sectional curvature of a hypersurface of ($\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, std metric, i), but I failed.
$$ V_{k}=\{(z_{0},...,z_{n})\in \mathbb{C}^{n+1} | \sum_{j}z_{j}^{k}=0\}- \{0\}$$ 
I don't know how to deal with implicit surfaces. I tried to expand the formula using $z_{j}=x_{j}+iy_{j}$, but it became messy. Could you give me an explicit formula?

Comment: Do you have a link to the definition of holomorphic sectional curvature?